# If $A$ is a nonempty subset of a group $G$, then $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $xA=A$ $\forall x \in A$

Tags: group-theory

The forward direction is immediate from the closure of $A\leq G$.

For the backwards, I can get the closure of $A$: for some $a$,$b$ $\in A$, $$aA=A \Rightarrow \exists x \in A: ab=x \Rightarrow ab \in A$$

But I can't get an identity or inverse. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The statement is false, as the condition is satisfied by the empty set, which is not a subgroup. You need to assume $A$ is nonempty.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, A is nonempty, I'll edit that.

Comment: If you know $A$ is nonempty, let $x\in A$. Then $xA=A$, so there exists $y\in A$ such that $xy=x$. And since $xA=A$, there exists $z\in A$ such that $xz=y$.

Comment: ahh... that should've been pretty obvious. xO

Answer (score 2):

Take any $x\in A$. Then $xA=A$. Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$ and you will get $x^{-1}A=A$. As $x\in A$ you get that $e=x^{-1}x\in x^{-1}A=A$. And from here $x^{-1}=x^{-1}e\in x^{-1}A=A$. So that way you get both the identity and inverses.